# Grass Particle System

Tags: particles

I recently watched the grass essentials video from andrew price at blender guru and he said that it would be easier to use objects of grass in a particle system rather than strands. How would you get your object and put it in a particle system?

Comment: realated: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5577/how-do-you-create-grass and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49862/is-grass-texture-or-3d-object and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31476/making-grass-difference-between-hair-particles-and-emitter

Comment: Short answer: You will have to model a few different grass types individually, with a few variations one by one and texture tgem by hand. Then you can use those in the particle system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Render Tab]

In the particles tab go down to the "**Render**" section.

Then Select the option "**Group**" and select the group you want to use.