# How can i model Montressor Spaceport from Treasure Planet?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, procedural, polycount

i've started a project about Treasure Planet, some ships are already done, but i don't know how i can model this thing, here is some references : [image]

https://youtu.be/MI1_3oqwsFk?list=PL4tadHw-sbDsPHuIFfT0E8XPk8LkNvqUZ

I was thinking of Kitbashing, but it making my pc laggy, even i've got a strong i7 core CPU.

Here is what i have done so far :

[image]

Comment: What are you really asking? How to model buildings? How to randomize buildings onto a plane? How to optimize your scene not to lag? Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: You can model some house variations and put them into a group. Then use particle hair system to scatter them onto your geometry (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56930/grass-particle-system). If the scene is too heavy I'd go into wireframe view.

Comment: Will try it, thanks, also one more question, can i use instancing to scatter the houses? like a particle modifier but with instance duplication instead?

Comment: Sure, you can use instancing, dupli-verts or dupli-faces too. Hair particles work like instances too, saves memory.